# How to export subset of data in QGIS to DXF

Tags: qgis, cartography, export, clip

I have QGIS loaded with multiple layers. I want to save to .dxf but the map is so massive it results in a very large file. I only need a small portion of the map, so I was wondering how I can crop the map into a smaller file.

Comment: What is your current method for saving the map to dxf?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Highlight layer in the Layers table of contents (TOC), then using the Select Features tool select only the features you want to convert
2. Next, right click layer name in TOC and select Save Selection As and define the format drop down to AutoCAD DXF
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for all other layers

Comment: ...I think QGIS 2.6 had some DXF export improvements...

Comment: @mapBaker, Good to know!